# How to set a handler for all loggers within a project?

Tags: python, logging

I want to use a memory logger in my project. It keeps track of the last n logging records. A minimal example main file looks like this:

```
import sys
import logging
from logging import StreamHandler
from test_module import do_stuff

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class MemoryHandler(StreamHandler):
    def __init__(self, n_logs: int):

        StreamHandler.__init__(self)
        self.n_logs = n_logs
        self.my_records = []

    def emit(self, record):
        self.my_records.append(self.format(record))
        self.my_records = self.my_records[-self.n_logs:]

    def to_string(self):
        return '\n'.join(self.my_records)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.INFO)

    mem_handler = MemoryHandler(n_logs=10)
    logger.addHandler(mem_handler)
    logger.info('hello')
    do_stuff()

    print(mem_handler.to_string())
```

The test module I am importing `do_stuff` from looks like this:

```py
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def do_stuff():
    logger.info('doing stuff')
```

When I run the main function two log statements appear. The one from main and the one from doing stuff, but the memory logger only receives "hello" and not "doing stuff":

```
INFO:__main__:hello
INFO:test_module:doing stuff
hello
```

I assume that this is because mem_handler is not added to the test_module logger. I can fix this by adding the mem_handler explicitely:

```
logging.getLogger('test_module').addHandler(mem_handler)
```

But in general I don't want to list all modules and add the mem_handler manually. How can I add the mem_handler to all loggers in my project?

Comment: It depends a bit on how the loggers are configured. In many case it is sufficient to add the handler to the root logger: `logging.getLogger()`.

Comment: it works. changing `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` to `logger = logging.getLogger()` in main.py does it.

Comment: @KlausD. if you want to write an answer, I'll accept

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Python logging system is federated. That means there is a tree like structure similar to the package structure. This structure works by logger name and the levels are separated by dots.

If you use the module's `__name__` to get the logger it will be equivalant to the dotted name of the package. for example:

```
package.subpackage.module
```

In this federated system a message is send up the loggers structure (unless one of the loggers is explicitly configured with `propagate=False`).

So, the best way to add a handler is to add it to the root logger on the top of the structure and make sure all loggers below propagate.

You can get the root logger with `logging.getLogger()` (without any name) and then add handlers or other configuration as you like.